# Get Remote Ip Address in a .NET CORE 2.1 app hosted in Azure as a Docker Linux

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, kudu

I'm trying get the Remote IP Address from client inside the controller of a AspNetCore 2.1 API, but I'm getting the same IP everytime (`Request.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString() == "::ffff:172.18.0.1"`).

My config for forwarded headers:

```
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All,
        RequireHeaderSymmetry = false,
        KnownProxies = {
            IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.18.0.0"),
            IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:172.18.0.1"),
            IPAddress.Parse("172.18.0.1"),
            IPAddress.Parse("172.18.0.0")
        }
    });
```

I'm using the  standart Dockerfile for AspNetCore 2.1 App.
Also inside of the Kudu dashboard of the Azure, I can see my real IP in the headers: `X-Client-IP`, and `X-Forwarded-For`, but still unable to get it in the request context.

What I'm missing? Theres another way to get the Remote Ip Address from Client?

Comment: Look at [Troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer#troubleshoot) section and try logging.

Comment: Solved using `Request.Headers["X-Client-IP"]`, but it only works in production

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: @LeeLiu Your answer was not helpful, I'm still unable to get the right IP Adress from `.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?`

Comment: Did you managed how to do this?

Comment: @desmati I moved to Kubernetes.

Answer (score -1):

We can use the code `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;` to get the client IP address,  i have tested your code and it worked fine.

Please do below troubleshoots:

1.Ensure we call method of `UseForwardedHeaders` before using other middlewares.

2.Forwarded Headers Middleware isn't enabled by default. Forwarded Headers Middleware must be enabled for an app to process forwarded headers with UseForwardedHeaders.

As a additional workaround, We can use `Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]` to get the IP address of client rather than `X-Client-IP`.

We can do as follows：

```
        string IpAddress = null;
        if (Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString().IndexOf(",") > 0)
        {
            IpAddress = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString().Split(',')[0];
        }
        else
        {
            IpAddress = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString();
        }
```